# Segue between Navigationcontroller and Tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers. First: NavigationController, Second: TableViewController and Third: DetailsTableViewController (connected respectively)

And then I need to add a custom top bar buttton to DetailsTableViewController but I can't. Because there is no NavigationController before the DetailsTableViewController. When I add a NavigationController between TableViewController and DetailsTableViewController, I can't figure out how to fix my code working again.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let DestEntryDetailedTableViewController : DetailsTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsTableViewController }
```

What's the best and acceptable way of doing this? How to connect direktly a connection between TableViewController and DetailsTableViewController?

Note: DetailsTableViewController is not detail view of TableViewController. It just another UITableViewController instance.

Comment: Connecting a table to a detail view is easy.  However, from your description, it seems that you are attempting to use a NavigationController in a way it was not designed. It will not work like that. Please elaborate on what this custom top bar is supposed to do and look like.

Comment: DetailsTableViewController is not detail view of TableViewController. It just another UITableViewController instance. I need to add a button (composer icon). I can add TableViewController but I can't add DetailsTableViewController

Comment: So you have 2 view controllers and on one of them you want a navigation bar because you want to put a button on that navigation bar. Is this correct?

Comment: I have already 3 view controllers. I want to add a new NavigationController between TableViewControlller and DetailsTableViewController to add top bar button. The final case there will be 4 view controllers: Nav.,Tab.,Nav.,Details.